# What is the value of this double sum in closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form-expressions, elementary-proofs

I encountered the following double sum which requires an evaluation.

> Is there a closed form for this?
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k^{-1}}{(n+1)(n+2)}.$$
>   Incidentally, it seems that the following gives (empirically) the same value. Does it?
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{2^{n-1}(n+1)}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\binom{n}{2k-1}}{2k-1}.$$

Comment: Likely no chance. Both Maple and Mathematica fail with it. Maple finds the inner sum in terms of the Lerch function (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function).

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says "By the limit test, the series diverges." http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(sum(1%2F(binomial(n,k)*(n%2B1)*(n%2B2)),k%3D0..n),n%3D0..infinity)

Comment: looks like $\pi^2/6$. Represent the inverse binomial as a Beta integral and transform the sum under integrand as a geometric progression.

Comment: $\sum\binom{n}k^{-1}<3$, so the series converges.

Comment: @Fedor Petrov: Yes, numeric calculations do  confirm your suggestion since the partial sum for $n$ from $1$ to $1000$ equals 1.142937063.

Comment: 1st time I tried Wolfram Alpha. Maybe last time, ha ha.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone: Strangely, WA is very sensitive to syntax: in correct Mathematica syntax [I get the opposite](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BSum%5B1%2FBinomial%5Bn,+k%5D,+%7Bk,+0,+n%7D%5D%2F((n+%2B+1)+(n+%2B+2)),+%7Bn,+0,++++Infinity%7D%5D): *"By the comparison test, the series converges."*

Comment: @Alex M.  I used Maple syntax, and WA accepted it, and it appeared to display properly, even though display is different than yours.

Comment: @user64494 how does it confirm? $\pi^2/6=1.6449\dots$

Comment: @Fedor Petrov: The term where $n=0$ equals 1/2 and $\pi^2/6=1.644934068$.

Comment: Numerical calculations do not confirm your suggestion, producing for the second sum from 1 to 2000 the value 1.12068617279184 (the code on demand).

Comment: [Binomial/Euler transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform) maybe?

Comment: @user64494 hm, I did not check it numerically, but I do not see a flaw in my proof (added to the answer.) Would you please recheck?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Consider the integral $$I=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{zdzdt}{(1-zt)(1-z(1-t))}=\sum_{k,j\geqslant 0} \int_0^1\int_0^1 z^{k+j+1}t^k(1-t)^jdzdt=\\
\sum_{k,j\geqslant 0} \frac1{k+j+2}\cdot \frac{k!j!}{(k+j+1)!},$$
that is your sum (denote $n=k+j$). For evaluating the integral, we first integrate by $t$, get $-2\log(1-z)/(2-z)$. Now denote $1-z=x$ and integrate $2\log x/(1+x)=2\log x(1-x+x^2-x^3+\dots)$ using $\int_0^1 -\log x\cdot x^m dx=\frac1{(m+1)^2}$. We get $2(1-1/4+1/9-1/16+\dots)=\pi^2/6$.

As for your second sum, it has indeed the same value which may be obtained similarly. We consider the integral
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac1x\left(\frac1{1-y\frac{1+x}2}-\frac1{1-y\frac{1-x}2}\right)dxdy=\\ \sum_n \int_0^1y^n dy\cdot 2^{1-n}\int_0^1\frac{(1+x)^n-(1-x)^n}{2x}dx,
$$ 
that is your sum (expand $(1+x)^n-(1-x)^n=2\sum \binom{n}{2k-1}x^{2k-1}$ and integrate).

If we integrate first in $x$, we get $-2\log(1-y)/(2-y)$, the same thing as in the first sum.

Comment: Good job, Fedor. Hope one can also solve (answer) the second part of the problem which I posted after your reply.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan added. I wonder why computations show another answer.

Comment: It might be that the 2nd series is slowly converging.

Comment: It converges as $\sum 1/n^2$,  1000 terms should give the accuracy about $1/1000$.