# Asymptotic rate for $\sum\binom{n}k^{-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, infinite-sequences

This [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301903/what-is-the-value-of-this-double-sum-in-closed-form) prompted me to ask:

> What is the second order asymptotic growth/decay rate for the sum
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{\binom{n}k}$$
>   as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: Elementary considerations give 2 + 2/n +4/(n(n-1)) + 12/(n(n-1)(n-2))  + (n-7) times terms of order at greatest n^{-4}.  How much finer growth do you want?  Gerhard "Thinks There's No Closed Form" Paseman, 2018.06.04.

Comment: If you start combining terms, you can get 2 + 2/(n-2) + a cubic term plus a quartic error term, but I doubt you will get as far as 2+ 2/(n-3).  That should be good enough.  Gerhard "We're Not Splitting Atoms Here" Paseman, 2018.06.04.

Comment: [Using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5En%5Cfrac1%7B%5Cbinom%7Bn%7Dk%7D%24&p=1) you can find a few posts on Mathematics that seem related. For example, [Compute $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/985851) or [Finding $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^n { n \choose k}^{-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4783)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sum can be written in the form, see [2-adic Logarithm and Resistance of n-dimensional Cube](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146285/2-adic-logarithm-and-resistance-of-n-dimensional-cube)
$$S_{n+1}=\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{2^k}{k}.$$
The last term in the sum gives the estimate $S_n>1.$ You can get sharper estimates taking more terms.

Comment: This converges slower than the original sum...

Answer (score 5):

The following asymptotic expansion is proved in https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.1757 (The Hypercube of Resistors, Asymptotic Expansions, and Preferential Arrangements, by Nicholas Pippenger. Published in  Mathematics Magazine 83(N5) (2010), 331-346):
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}=2\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n(n-1)}+\ldots \frac{k!}{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}+O(\frac{1}{n^{k+1}})\right).$$

**P.S.** This result confirms the answer given in the Gerhard Paseman's comment.

Comment: For k less than sqrt(n)-3, the terms look a little like a geometric sequence with common ratio more  than order of sqrt(n), giving that the middle terms add up to less than (1 +2/sqrt(n)) times the kth term.  Even for most k less than n/3, the middle terms add up to less than (1+ 2log_2(n)) times the kth term.  So the O term above can be given an explicit constant for many k and n sufficiently large.  Gerhard "Simple Estimates Are The Best" Paseman, 2018.06.05.